# how to convert string to dropdown control or find a control in datalist with control.client id known asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, casting, selectedindexchanged, nested-datalist

i have a datalist which contain two dropdownCountry in a datalistCity and a button to dynamically add dropdownCountry and datalistCity i want to populate dropdowncity on DropdownCountry selectedindex change code is below

aspx code

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DDSubOffCity"   OnSelectedIndexChanged='GetSelectedCityValue' AutoPostBack="false" runat="server" Width="355px"> <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem> </asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DDSubOffCountry" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged='GetSelectedCountryValue'  AutoPostBack="true" Width="355px">  <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem> </asp:DropDownList>
```

code behind datalist itembound

```
DDSubOffCountry.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript:NewBufferDDCountryValue('" + DDSubOffCountry.ClientID + "','" + DDSubOffCountry.SelectedValue + "');");
            DDSubOffCity.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript:NewBufferDDCityValue('" + DDSubOffCity.ClientID + "', '" + DDSubOffCity.SelectedValue + "');");}
```

javascript code

```
function NewBufferDDCountryValue(objddCountry) 
        {
            try {
                if (objddCountry != 'null') {
                    var ctlDDl = objddCountry.toString();
                    var parts = ctlDDl.split('_', 4);
                    var indexId = parts[3];
                    var objHidden = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_DataListOffices_hiddenDDSubOffCountry_' + indexId);
                    objHidden.value = document.getElementById(objddCountry).value;
                }
            } catch (e) { alert(e); }
        }

        function NewBufferDDCityValue(objddCity) 
        {
            try {
                if (objddCity != 'null') {
                    var ctlDDl = objddCity.toString();
                    var parts = ctlDDl.split('_', 4);
                    var indexId = parts[3];
                    var objHidden = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_DataListOffices_hiddenDDSubOffCity_' + indexId);
                    objHidden.value = document.getElementById(objddCity).value;
                }
            } catch (e) { alert(e); }    
        }
```

the function which will be called on code behind when onselectedindexchange event occurs

```
public void GetSelectedCountryValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList drp = (DropDownList)sender;

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), " ", "javascript:NewBufferDDCountryValue('" + drp.ClientID + "');", true);
        var city = new City();
        string indexer = drp.ClientID;
        indexer=indexer.Split(Convert.ToChar("_"))[3];
        string senderCity ="ContentPlaceHolder1_DataListOffices_DDSubOffCity_" + indexer;

        DropDownList drpCity;
       /*****************/
```

how to find a cntrol if its Client ID is Known only. or how to cast a string to dropdownCity to be populated
            drpCity = FindControl(senderCity);

```
       /********************/

        city.populateCity(drpCity, drp.SelectedValue);
    }
```

in GetSelectedCountryValue function you can see that i have the index of dropdownCountry 
know i now the name of the control but couldnt figure it out how to find that control through only its ClientId any help is appreciated.

Comment: your javascript function does not take two parameter. but you are passing two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The GetSelectedCountryValue is a C# method so you can directly use DDSubOffCountry.SelectedItem.Text because the DropDownList is a Web Server Control

Comment: even ddSubOffCity is a Web Server Control so you can use the same way as Country DropDown like this ddSubOffCity.SelectedItem.Text

Comment: <asp:Button ID="BtnAddAnoOff" runat="server" Text="Add Another Office" CausesValidation="false"
                                                OnClick="ButtonAddAnotherOffice_Click" OnClientClick="showProgress()" />